# How to concatenate in mule logger?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I need to concatenate text with json payload in logger component. I have tried below ways but no luck

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="38de876a-a64f-4d83-86a1-ef4cbbda167c" message="#['payload is:' + payload]"/>
```

Even i don't see any transformers like 'object to string converter' in mule 3.

Please suggest syntax for mule 4

Answer (score 1):

Try separating the text from your dataweave

i.e.

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" mesage="Payload is: #[payload]" doc:id="38de876a-a64f-4d83-86a1-ef4cbbda167c" />
```

All the various transformers were removed in Mule 4 due to the payload always being "accessible". That is, regardless of the payload type (XML, JSON, Java, CSV...) you can access fields through payload.{fieldname}. In Mule 3.x the payload had to be coerced to a Java object to allow that. You can explicitly set the output type of any dataweave expression, so you can also try:

```
mesage="Payload is: #[output application/java --- payload]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working with below syntax

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="38de876a-a64f-4d83-86a1-ef4cbbda167c" message="#['payload is:' ++ payload]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the below worked for me...

```
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="35d4566e-02ba-495a-bd40-c30aa5a90413" message="#['Get Accounts Response Paylaod : #[payload]']"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).